# Building SpringBoot GraalVM native image with -H parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, graalvm-native-image

*What I am trying to achieve:*

I have a graalVM springboot image which is working fine. It is doing correct business logic, etc.

With that said, I would like to build the native image with parameters, such as:  `-H:IncludeResources`

*What did I try:*

Following online tutorials, I build the native image using

```
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
```

and then

`mvn -Pnative native:compile`

It seems Spring takes care of the build, not allowing me to specify the `-H` parameter.

*Question:*

How to build the image with `-H` arguments?

Comment: as [explained](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/dynamic-features/Resources/) that is a parameter for building not "runtime" meaning when you compile your code you use "-H:IncludeResources" which will include the resources at the output native image.

Comment: You are correct, thanks for pointing out. Corrected, upvoted your comment

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters to `native-image` using `<buildArgs>` element:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
  <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <buildArgs>
      <buildArg>-H:IncludeResources=...</buildArg>
    </buildArgs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

See this [GraalVM doc](https://graalvm.github.io/native-build-tools/latest/maven-plugin.html#configuration-reusing-config-from-parent) for more details